# My function JS working only in the first time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple budget generator, and I have a function that calculates the sum of columns, but for some reason it only works once. It only works again when I refresh the page. I don't have much experience, but I feel like it should be something simple. Can you guys help me?

I have a button to call the function

First time, the function works
[image]

After clicking the button again, it doesn't
[image]

```js
function somax(tableId, column, resultId) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  var rows = table.rows;
  var total = 0;
  var cell;

  for (var i = 1, iLen = rows.length - 1; i < iLen; i++) {
    cell = rows[i].cells[column];
    total += Number(cell.textContent || cell.innerText);
  }

  document.getElementById(resultId).innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById(resultId).innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
  });

}
```

I have some fixed values ​​that multiply the amount entered in the input, then the total value of the column must be added

```
    

function planos() {

  

    // definição dos campos de quantidade
    
      var indice = document.getElementById("primary").value;
      var childSelect1 = document.getElementById("child1").value;
      var childSelect2 = document.getElementById("child2").value;
      var childSelect3 = document.getElementById("child3").value;
      var childSelect4 = document.getElementById("child4").value;
      var childSelect5 = document.getElementById("child5").value;
      var childSelect6 = document.getElementById("child6").value;
    
    
      // definição dos campos de quantidade, enfermaria e apartamento
      var tble00a18 = document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML;
      var tble19a23 = document.getElementById("value6").innerHTML;
      var tble24a28 = document.getElementById("value10").innerHTML;
      var tble29a33 = document.getElementById("value14").innerHTML;
      var tble34a38 = document.getElementById("value18").innerHTML;
      var tble39a43 = document.getElementById("value22").innerHTML;
      var tble44a48 = document.getElementById("value26").innerHTML;
      var tble49a53 = document.getElementById("value30").innerHTML;
      var tble54a58 = document.getElementById("value34").innerHTML;
      var tble59 = document.getElementById("value38").innerHTML;
    
      var x00a18 = document.getElementById("value3");
      var x19a23 = document.getElementById("value7");
      var x24a28 = document.getElementById("value11");
      var x29a33 = document.getElementById("value15");
      var x34a38 = document.getElementById("value19");
      var x39a43 = document.getElementById("value23");
      var x44a48 = document.getElementById("value27");
      var x49a53 = document.getElementById("value31");
      var x54a58 = document.getElementById("value35");
      var x59 = document.getElementById("value39");
    
      var y00a18 = document.getElementById("value4");
      var y19a23 = document.getElementById("value8");
      var y24a28 = document.getElementById("value12");
      var y29a33 = document.getElementById("value16");
      var y34a38 = document.getElementById("value20");
      var y39a43 = document.getElementById("value24");
      var y44a48 = document.getElementById("value28");
      var y49a53 = document.getElementById("value32");
      var y54a58 = document.getElementById("value36");
      var y59 = document.getElementById("value40");
    
      // YOU saúde 
    
      var enf_plan = document.getElementById("headerENF");
      var apto_plan = document.getElementById("headerAPTO");
    
    
      var YOUsmileudi00a18 = 131.70;
      var YOUsmileudi19a23 = 170.34;
      var YOUsmileudi24a28 = 190.79;
      var YOUsmileudi29a33 = 213.68;
      var YOUsmileudi34a38 = 240.54;
      var YOUsmileudi39a43 = 271.16;
      var YOUsmileudi44a48 = 338.96;
      var YOUsmileudi49a53 = 406.75;
      var YOUsmileudi54a58 = 553.91;
      var YOUsmileudi59 = 784.93;
    
      var YOUhappyudi00a18 = 160.66;
      var YOUhappyudi19a23 = 207.83;
      var YOUhappyudi24a28 = 232.76;
      var YOUhappyudi29a33 = 260.68;
      var YOUhappyudi34a38 = 293.46;
      var YOUhappyudi39a43 = 330.83;
      var YOUhappyudi44a48 = 413.53;
      var YOUhappyudi49a53 = 496.26;
      var YOUhappyudi54a58 = 675.78;
      var YOUhappyudi59 = 957.59;
    
    
      // FUNÇÕES CONDICIONAIS YOU
    
      var YOUsmileudi00a18 = parseFloat(tble00a18) * YOUsmileudi00a18;
      var YOUsmileudi19a23 = parseFloat(tble19a23) * YOUsmileudi19a23;
      var YOUsmileudi24a28 = parseFloat(tble24a28) * YOUsmileudi24a28;
      var YOUsmileudi29a33 = parseFloat(tble29a33) * YOUsmileudi29a33;
      var YOUsmileudi34a38 = parseFloat(tble34a38) * YOUsmileudi34a38;
      var YOUsmileudi39a43 = parseFloat(tble39a43) * YOUsmileudi39a43;
      var YOUsmileudi44a48 = parseFloat(tble44a48) * YOUsmileudi44a48;
      var YOUsmileudi49a53 = parseFloat(tble49a53) * YOUsmileudi49a53;
      var YOUsmileudi54a58 = parseFloat(tble54a58) * YOUsmileudi54a58;
      var YOUsmileudi59 = parseFloat(tble59) * YOUsmileudi59;
    
      var YOUhappyudi00a18 = parseFloat(tble00a18) * YOUhappyudi00a18;
      var YOUhappyudi19a23 = parseFloat(tble19a23) * YOUhappyudi19a23;
      var YOUhappyudi24a28 = parseFloat(tble24a28) * YOUhappyudi24a28;
      var YOUhappyudi29a33 = parseFloat(tble29a33) * YOUhappyudi29a33;
      var YOUhappyudi34a38 = parseFloat(tble34a38) * YOUhappyudi34a38;
      var YOUhappyudi39a43 = parseFloat(tble39a43) * YOUhappyudi39a43;
      var YOUhappyudi44a48 = parseFloat(tble44a48) * YOUhappyudi44a48;
      var YOUhappyudi49a53 = parseFloat(tble49a53) * YOUhappyudi49a53;
      var YOUhappyudi54a58 = parseFloat(tble54a58) * YOUhappyudi54a58;
      var YOUhappyudi59 = parseFloat(tble59) * YOUhappyudi59;
     if (childSelect1 == "0") {
    
        enf_plan.innerHTML = "Smile UDI ENFERMARIA";
        apto_plan.innerHTML = "Smile UDI APARTAMENTO";
    
        x00a18.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi00a18.toFixed(2);
        x19a23.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi19a23.toFixed(2);
        x24a28.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi24a28.toFixed(2);
        x29a33.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi29a33.toFixed(2);
        x34a38.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi34a38.toFixed(2);
        x39a43.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi39a43.toFixed(2);
        x44a48.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi44a48.toFixed(2);
        x49a53.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi49a53.toFixed(2);
        x54a58.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi54a58.toFixed(2);
        x59.innerHTML = YOUsmileudi59.toFixed(2);
    
        y00a18.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi00a18.toFixed(2);
        y19a23.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi19a23.toFixed(2);
        y24a28.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi24a28.toFixed(2);
        y29a33.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi29a33.toFixed(2);
        y34a38.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi34a38.toFixed(2);
        y39a43.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi39a43.toFixed(2);
        y44a48.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi44a48.toFixed(2);
        y49a53.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi49a53.toFixed(2);
        y54a58.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi54a58.toFixed(2);
        y59.innerHTML = YOUhappyudi59.toFixed(2);
      }
      else {
        enf_plan.innerHTML = "";
        apto_plan.innerHTML = "";
    
        x00a18.innerHTML = "";
        x19a23.innerHTML = "";
        x24a28.innerHTML = "";
        x29a33.innerHTML = "";
        x34a38.innerHTML = "";
        x39a43.innerHTML = "";
        x44a48.innerHTML = "";
        x49a53.innerHTML = "";
        x54a58.innerHTML = "";
        x59.innerHTML = "";
    
        y00a18.innerHTML = "";
        y19a23.innerHTML = "";
        y24a28.innerHTML = "";
        y29a33.innerHTML = "";
        y34a38.innerHTML = "";
        y39a43.innerHTML = "";
        y44a48.innerHTML = "";
        y49a53.innerHTML = "";
        y54a58.innerHTML = "";
        y59.innerHTML = "";
      }
    }
```

Comment: How and when do you call this function initially? You may need to consider calling it again at the appropriate time.

Comment: can you make variables 'total' and 'cell' a global variables. Other words, move them outside of somax function

Comment: Fadi, it only worked at the first time too, after only get "NaN" :-(

Comment: if you can upload the entire code on JSFiddle, perhaps I can help by trying out some solutions.